# Reference domain when calling PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials externally in C#

Tags: c#, credentials

I am confused about what the domain parameter should reference when calling `ValidateCredentials.ValidateCredentials`.

It seems simple at first, when you are calling from within the company network it is just the domain name eg myDomainName.adr, or the shorthand version you use when logging in - ie `myDomainName` from [myDomainName]\myUserName.

However, what should you use externally? An IP that resolves to the Domain Controller? Or do you need a specific LDAP service setting up that is externally facing?

Thanks

Comment: I am sure, you're missing tags here. Never heard of `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` and such.

Comment: You have to be on a domain, in order to login to it.  You can do this by either being in a facility and connecting to their connected wired or Wi-Fi network, or using a VPN connecting to the organization.  A VPN setup can't be manufactured on your side. They have to have some means for you to be able to connect to a VPN so that you can access their network and, subsequently, their domain controller.

Comment: This is the method I am referring to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks RLH, guess I might be using the wrong call then / barking up the wrong tree!

Comment: You need to use one of the overloaded constructors for `PrincipalContext` to be able to specify the domain (and possibly the "starting point") you want to use